# ImportError when running python script inside docker image using silent mode miniconda3 to install the dependencies

Tags: python, linux, docker, miniconda

I tried to run the python script using the docker image built, which has installed the silent mode miniconda3 and pip all the needed packages. But I am keeping getting error of ImportError as following. How should I fix it?
Here is the code attached

```
FROM diannepat/fsl6-core:latest


ENV PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"
ARG PATH="/root/miniconda3/bin:${PATH}"

# Grab latest miniconda installer
RUN wget --no-check-certificate https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
&& bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -b \
&& rm -f Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh \
&& conda update -y conda \
&& conda install -y pip \
&& pip3 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install flywheel-sdk \
&& pip3 --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org install nipype

ENV FLYWHEEL=/flywheel/v0
RUN mkdir -p ${FLYWHEEL}
COPY run.py ${FLYWHEEL}/run.py
CMD [ "python", "./run.py"]
```

The error message looks like the following:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYUg5.png)

Comment: What commands do you run to generate that error?  If it's `docker build`, which specific step fails?  Is the error literally the text `Error message`, or is there a more complete error?  Please edit the question to include the actual text of the error (in the question and not behind a link; as text and not an image).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the workdir layer to specify the current working directory?

`WORKDIR ${FLYWHEEL}`

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/